# How to autosize the height of a list view in XAML

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin

My list view object receives an image, an ID number and a synopsis. The synopsis varies in size because some have whitespace returns. I notice that ListView has a row height that I can set (which I have set at 250 right now), but it can only be a fixed value. So what happens, is my grid becomes too big height wise for the ListView, causing it to overflow and overlay onto the next listed item. Is there anyway to auto size the list view in XAML?

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding List}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" RowHeight="250" SelectedItem="SelectedCTR" SeparatorVisibility="None">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.Row="0" HeightRequest="100" MinimumWidthRequest="160" WidthRequest="160" Source="{Binding AttachedmentData,Converter={StaticResource stringToImage}}" />
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Number}" Font="19"
                             TextColor="#f35e20" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding TrimmedSynopsis}" Font="17"
                             TextColor="#503026" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Which technology is this? Xamarin?

Comment: Have you tried not to set height? In XAML on Windows it would work like that out of box.

Comment: Yes, the listview has a default fixed height that is quite small, and that makes it much worse, since there is a lot of overflow.

Comment: And yes, I am using Xamarin in visual studio

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> You need to add `HasUnevenRows` to **True** and let unset the `RowHeight` property.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding List}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HasUnevenRows="True" SelectedItem="SelectedCTR" SeparatorVisibility="None">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.Row="0" HeightRequest="100" MinimumWidthRequest="160" WidthRequest="160" Source="{Binding AttachedmentData,Converter={StaticResource stringToImage}}" />
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Number}" Font="19"
                             TextColor="#f35e20" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding TrimmedSynopsis}" Font="17"
                             TextColor="#503026" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 5):

Set only *ListView* property `HasUnevenRows="True"`

Answer (score 2):

When you use [Syncfusion Listview](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sflistview/getting-started) than

```
AutoFitMode="DynamicHeight"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
```

Properties works fine.